# Is it possible to use VS Code as an Dynamics AX editor?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7

Is it possible to use VS Code as an Dynamics 365 for Operations editor?

It means:

- AOT objects editor
- X++ code editor
- xRefs using

Yes, I know about project 'VSCode for NAV':

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTY5VELbCWI
- https://github.com/Microsoft/AL

What about AX7?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Currently it is not even possible to set up your own develoment machine for AX7, you have to download a VM from Microsoft. There are several components aside from Visual Studio needed for development and I think it highly unlikely that they can be ported to VS Code without some heavy reengineering.

Comment: In the Visual Studio Code extensions [website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode) there is no sign of an X++ (or AX7) extension...

Comment: The following link may be of interest: http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2017/02/ax7-development-tools-without-vm/

Comment: I found this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexk.vscode-xpp - haven't had a play yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Specific Visual Studio tools are included when you deploy a D365 for Finance and Operations, Enterprise edition developer box. This **is** the editor to use with the product.

Comment: Thanks ) It is a well known info.

My question is: __Is it possible to use VS Code as an Dynamics 365 for Operations editor?__

Comment: No it not possible to use VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 is the exclusive integrated development environment (IDE) for development.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-tools/development-tools-overview